# Simple justification that function sends a nonzero probability density to a nonzero probability density

Tags: probability

There is a certain nice (like analytic) function $g$ such that for random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have $Y=g(X)$. We know that the pdf $p_X(0)\neq 0$. I'd like to justify that $p_Y(g(0))\neq 0$ with a simple argument. I know that $$p_Y(y)=\sum_{f(x_k)=y}\frac{p_X(x)}{|dy/dx|}\Big|_{x=x_k}$$ holds, but I'd like to avoid using this formula to make our argument as prerequisite-less as possible. If necessary, you can assume $X$ is the uniform distribution on a certain segment on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you knew $X$ was uniform on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)=x$, how would you know what the density of $Y$ would be at $0$?

Comment: Or if $g(x)=k$ for some constant $k$, does $Y$ have a density at $k$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I can come up with a simple argument with your inputs.

Comment: Density functions are not unique. They are defined only upto sets of measure zero. So the question has no meaning.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right. I think my actual problem was reformulated to a well-posed one, which I resolved. Thank you, anyway.